# Python validate multiple values using if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

Example1 To Check single Value:

```
def validate(self, data, check, col):
    output = []
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        try:
            if value[col] == check:
                output.append("{},{},Passed".format(key,value[col]))
            else:
                output.append("{},{},Failed".format(key,value[col]))
        except IndexError as e:
            pass
    return output


data1 = {key1:['a','b','c','ok'], key2:['a','b','c','down']}
check = "ok"
col = 3
print self.validate(data1, check, col)
```

Output:

```
['key1','ok','Passed', 'key2','down','Failed']
```

Example2 To Check two values:

```
 data1 = {key1:['a','b','c','ok', "True"], key2:['a','b','c','down', "False"]}

 def validate(self, data, check1, check2, col1, col2):
    output = []
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        try:
            if value[col1] == check1 and value[col2] == check2:
                output.append("{},{},{},Passed".format(key,value[col1], value[col2]))
            else:
                output.append("{},{},Failed".format(key,value[col1], value[col2]))
        except IndexError as e:
            pass
    return output
```

is there a way that I can achieve the above two examples in one code (Validate multiple values one, two, three, four)

Answer (score 2):

why not use `all` with zipped lists of columns/check values?

```
if all(value[col] == check for col,check in zip((col1,col2),(check1,check2))):
```

If you have more parameters, I suggest that you turn:

```
def validate(self, data, check1, check2, col1, col2):
```

into

```
def validate(self, data, check_values, columns):
```

so you can adapt to:

```
if all(value[col] == check for col,check in zip(columns,check_values)):
```

and further, since those values and columns are linked, maybe pass directly a list of tuples or a dictionary linking them together to `validate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all the output in one object/return, we can make some adjustment to your first function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def validate(data, check_value, column_index):
    # validating whether the list item at column_index == check_value
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in data.items():  # for python2, use data.iteritems()
        if check_value in v and column_index <= len(v) and v[column_index] == check_value:
            output[check_value].append({k: [v[column_index], 'passed']})
        else:
            output[check_value].append({k: [v[column_index], 'failed']})
    return output
```

This should return the same expected results for your single value tests.

And you can do something like this for multiple values:

```
check_values = ['ok', 'b']
column_indices = [3, 2]

for value, index in zip(check_values, column_indices):
    validate(data, value, index)
```

Which returns:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ok': [{'key1': ['ok', 'passed']}, {'key2': ['down', 'failed']}]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [{'key1': ['c', 'failed']}, {'key2': ['c', 'failed']}]})
```